# @ is not allowed as an instance variable name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid3

I am currently working on a project with mongoid and rails. Here is the code:

```
class Account
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :account_name, type: String

  has_many :groups
end

class Group
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :group_name, type: String

  belongs_to :account
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_login, :find_company

  def new
    @group = @company.groups.new
  end

  def create
    @group = @company.groups.new params[:group]
    if @group.save
      redirect_to people_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def find_company
    @company = current_account.groups.find(params[:company_id]) if params[:company_id]
  end
end
```

And the error that is being returned is:

```
@' is not allowed as an instance variable name (NameError)
./app/controllers/groups_controller.rb:5:in `new'
```

I can't seem to find much googling around for the issue, but it would appear the issue lies with the has_and_belongs_to_many relationship, but I am not certain.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: i guess the error would also be if `params[:company_id]` returns nil, then you are calling `groups.new` on a `nil` object.

Comment: What Ruby version are you using? `ruby -v`

Comment: once can you try this? `@group = @company.groups.build` in `new` action.

Comment: @Zippie -- that would cause something like `NoMethodError: undefined method 'groups' for nil`

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was misunderstanding has_and_belongs_to_many. I have resolved the issue by removing that!

Thanks guys for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason was that the db connection was not properly configured :?